# Emails won't download to Outlook (dovecot, postfix, debian)

Tags: debian, outlook, dovecot

I finally managed to set up dovecot and postfix to the point where I can connect to my server with Outlook to send emails.
Receiving emails works too, but I can not download them to my mail client:
Emails are saved in /home/USERNAME/Maildir/new and I can access them via SSH. But they are not getting downloaded into Outlook when I click send & receive.
The only item in my Outlook inbox is the Outlook test message for some reason.
Sending from Outlook works fine.
There don't seem to be any obvious errors in the mail .err/.info/.warn files.
I am connected with IMAP.
Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Check your Outlook settings, specifically the one related to the default IMAP folder.  You might need to specify that new mail arrives in Maildir/new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving email from IMAP is independent of the ability to send email which uses a separate SMTP service.  Please remove postfix from the tags as it is irrelevant in this case.

Dovecot will require an encrypted connection before it will allow a login.  You can generate a self-signed certificate and add it as the SSL key and certificate to your Dovecot configuration.  I configure Dovecot with both to listen on the IMAP and IMAPS ports.  The IMAP port will use StartTLS to begin the encrypted session.  Encryption is not required on when connecting from the server where Dovecot is running.

You must also specify one or more password stores.  Try running `dovecot -n | less` to view your configuration.

The process I used to get login working was:

- Configure login and test locally.
- Configure TLS/SSL certificates and test locally.
- Test remotely. (I used Thunderbird to do initial testing.)

Dovecot activity should be logged in `/var/log/mail.log`.